# Code won't execute when RESTlet status is changed to 'Released'

Tags: oracle, netsuite

I've written a RESTlet that works in our Sandbox environment. However, when I move the code to production and change the status to 'Released' and the Debug Level to 'Error', my code disappears. Specifically, I have a user event that creates a button that executes a RESTlet. I can see the button when the status is 'Testing', but as soon as the status gets changed to 'Released' I can no longer see the button. I haven't found much information on this, and it seems like this could be  permissions error, but our Admin is out and I can't change my own permissions - is there a workaround to this?

I've tried changing the logging level and status levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the `Audience` on the Script Deployment record? Once you Release the Script, it is only accessible to the Employees/Roles/Groups/etc specified in the Audience.

Comment: @Erictgraubaugh  This worked! Thank you so much! I can't believe you responded - I love your blog and videos!! Thank you so much for making the NetSuite community better!  I hope your new family is doing well also!